# CSS Selector, find first appearance in an nested content

Tags: css, selector

I tried some different things to get the first element to set its display property to block, the rest should be set to none. But I'm not able to get just the first appearance of the element, every time I use a selector I get all elements or none of them. Maybe some of you know some CSS Tricks to solve my Prob.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="some_class">
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p> 
<p> <object height="300" width="480"></object></p> 
<p> <object height="300" width="480"></object></p> 
<p> <object height="300" width="480"></object></p> 
<p>...</p></div>
```

I need to get the first appearance of "object". I can't change the HTML and have to find a way to get this problem solved by using a nice CSS selector. Anybody an idea?

I tried code like: `.some_class p > object:first-of-type`
but that way every "object" gets selected... because every "object" is the first of its type of their parent "p".

Answer (score 1):

> Note: This will only work when elements are static, can change
>   `nth-of-type()` for `p`, but if the elements are dynamic, you need to
>   go for JavaScript

Try this

```
.some_class p:nth-of-type(1) object {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

This will select all objects in `p` element, so use this if you only have a single object element in p, if you've multiple than use this

```
.some_class p:nth-of-type(1) object:nth-of-type(1) {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Comment: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YVYsf/) converted `object` to `img` here. Notice it's not working (probably due to the first `p` not containing any `img`.

Comment: @ralph.m No, my solution is wrong, am choosing 1st p tag but am working on it

Comment: Huh, I tested it an it seemed to work, even though I didn't expect it to. O well ...

Comment: @ralph.m Nah it wont, it will select 1st p with `...` which is not having any child object so it will fail

Comment: Yeah, that's what I expected. Must not have done a proper browser refresh when I tested it (having disabled the JS I was trying).

Comment: Thx everybody for your answers. Mr. Alien is right, that won't work because it will select the 1st p and that maybe does not habe any objects inside. But I appreciate the approach. :)

Comment: @SylarI-i You need to use JS for this :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Thx for your effort. So you don't think there is a CSS-way? I couldn't find a solution either, but thought maybe some you know some tricks. ^^ Thx anyway. :)

Comment: @SylarI-i You welcome :) and I suppose no CSS solution till now, I've asked a question here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396376/how-do-we-select-first-occurence-of-an-element-in-the-entire-document-using-css

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something similar to this

> `div.some_class:first-child p object { display:block;}`

I'm not sure if this works, but it will work for this kind of structure

> `div.some_class:first-child .some_class2 { display:block;}`

Comment: Thx, I tried it and all objects in the div get selected. :)
That prob really is ... a prob. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In case it's of interest, a simple line of JS can do this:

```
document.querySelector("p object").style.display = "block";
```

(Just having fun with `querySelector()`, as it's new to me.)

Comment: Thank you for that hint, but I really have to use CSS. :)

Comment: It may not be possible, in which case you might have to use a different strategy. We don't know the context of your code, but it looks like an awkward setup. The obvious solution would be to wrap your objects in something other than a `<p>`.

Comment: Yeah the setup *anotherwordfor:notgood*. But that content is generated dynamically by JSPs and CMS. ^^ Thank you anyway. :)