# How do we select first occurence of an element in the entire document using CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395772/css-selector-find-first-appearance-in-an-nested-content/16395802?noredirect=1#comment23502880_16395802) question stumped me

Say suppose we have a structure like this

```
<!-- Elements can be dynamic -->
<div>
  <section>

  </section>
  <section>
    <p>1st Para</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>2nd Para</p>
  </section>
  <section>

  </section>
</div>
```

Now in this case how do I select only 1st instance of `p` element?

Note: Sections can be dynamic so

```
div section:nth-of-type(2) p {
   /* This won't work */
}
```

Comment: This has been asked before. There isn't a way to do it in pure CSS. I'll look up the old question.

Comment: Here's a question which has several options for a specific structure, but that structure isn't the same as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15712377/1180785

Comment: @Dave Thank you, will delete my question.

Comment: Well it's a slightly different question, so might be worth keeping. Maybe somebody knows a workaround for this exact situation?

Comment: @Dave I think there's no work around for this if elements are dynamic, cuz I searched, I tried, but failed

Comment: Yeah, I'm inclined to agree.

Comment: I think if there is some complicated css selector for this, that wouldn't be too cross-browser friendly, so jquery is the easiest way. You can use `$('p:first').css({'color':'red'});` , too.

Comment: @Seer We always have JS, but wanted to go with CSS :)

Comment: Yeah, if you have an axe, use that for cutting a tree, not your knife :) The knife is perfect for slice your bread :)

Comment: @Seer haha yes, now we can animate things with CSS3, so I wondered if I was missing something here

Comment: animation is another question, but until we have browsers which don't support this, I think the most practical is to select the element with jQuery, so you can make jquery fallback for older browsers and add a state-class for css animation. But I think you know these things, too :))

Comment: @Seer Well that was just an example ;) here the only thing is to select elements 1st occurrence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible using CSS alone. You mentioned that the elements get dynamically generated, if that is the case then I would programmatically put a class on the first `<p>` and target it that way.

By doing this you will also ensure cross-browser compatibility; since if it *were* possible, you would most definitely have to use CSS3 pseudo-classes.

Answer (score 0):

use `p:first` , `p:second` and it will work like a class but you don't need to add `.anyclass` in yout html tag. Hope this helps.